# Annotations in Application class are red, but everything is working, is it normal?

Tags: android

I opened the file Application.java, then on the top appeared dialog like you need to update something(I have not read properly and clicked authomatically), then every single annotation turned red denoting error[Screenshot from IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwBLt.png). It seems like my app is working properly,should I leave my Application.java class in rest?

Answer (score 0):

It can happen when your Android Studio loses sync with the generated code by annotations. Sometimes using gradle sync solves the issue, and in case it doesn't, try going the menu **File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart**

Comment: Still red( Invalidated Caches